# Regular expression to extract data from a table in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regular expression and python:
I have a data stored in a log file which I need to extract using regular expression. Below is the format :

```
#bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]
   0         1000         0.01         0.03         0.02
   4         1000       177.69       177.88       177.79
   8         1000       175.90       176.07       176.01
  16         1000       181.51       181.73       181.60
  32         1000       199.64       199.81       199.72
  64         1000       228.10       228.27       228.19
  28         1000       278.70       278.90       278.75
  256         1000       388.26       388.49       388.39
  512         1000       593.49       593.82       593.63
  1024         1000      1044.27      1044.90      1044.59
```

Comment: What is the desired output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How is this file formatted? tab seperated? (csv)?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: So.. since when is SO a platform for requesting not-paid hiring..?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` or regex to get a specific column. Split is cleaner for this case:

```
import re
with open("input") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        # using split to get the 4th column
        print line.split()[3]
        # using regex to get the 4th column
        print re.match(r'^\s*(?:[^\s]+[\s]+){3}([^\s]+)', line).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use regular expressions, then this script does the trick:

```
import re

number_pattern = '(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'
line_pattern = '^\s+%s\s+$' % ('\s+'.join([number_pattern for x in range(5)]))

f = open('data', 'r')
for line in f:
  match = re.match(line_pattern, line)
  if match is not None:
    print match.groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need (\S+)

```
import re
pattern=re.compile('(\S+)')
f=open('data.txt', 'r')
for l in f.readlines():
    print pattern.findall(l)
```

you can also do the other way

```
import re
whitespace=re.compile('\s+')
    f=open('data.txt', 'r')
    for l in f.readlines():
        print whitespace.split(l.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) function from [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) instead:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.genfromtxt("yourlogfile.dat",skip_header=1)
```

`a` will be an array of all your data.